# loop over a query to create an Manual ArryOfStructs Data

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am have a query data and want to create a manual array of structs with it, i am using this code but it seems wrong. what i am missing here what should do it here

```
for(i in myquery) {
                st['Contact'][#i#]['ID'] = i.id;
                st['Contact'][#i#]['Name'] = i.name;
                st['Contact'][#i#]['Email'] = i.email;
            }
```

Comment: What does not work? What do you believe does *#i#* do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues in your code. I'm going to break this down:

Let's assume you have a query result like the follwing:

```javascript
myquery= queryNew(
            "id, name, email",
            "integer,varchar,varchar",
            [ 
                {"id":43,"name":"Antonio", "email": "antonio@somedomain.com"}, 
                {"id":65,"name":"Manuel", "email": "manuel@somedomain.com"}, 
                {"id":77,"name":"Paula", "email": "paula@somedomain.com"},
                {"id":87,"name":"Jennifer", "email": "Jennifer@somedomain.com"}
                
            ]);
```

Then iterating (looping) through your query with a `for( row in query )` like you did won't work:

```javascript
    for( i in myquery ){
       st['Contact'][#i#]['ID'] = i.id;
       st['Contact'][#i#]['Name'] = i.name;
       st['Contact'][#i#]['Email'] = i.email;
    }
```

The cause:

- When using a `for( row in myquery )` you are iterating the query by row. But in your loop you want to make use of an index `i` to set your arrays. Then, `i` is not going to be a numeric integer that you are expecting, but a complete rowset. It will try using the complete row as index, and that shouldn't work. If you need an index, you MUST also iterate your query by index, e.g. with `for (i = 1; i <= myquery.recordCount; i++)`. As a reference please see how to iterate a query by index see [cfdocs here](https://cfdocs.org/cfloop#:%7E:text=Loop%20over%20a%20Query%20(Script%20Syntax)), or alternatively use the `ArrayAppend()` or `append()` member without using any index.
- You need to pre define `st['Contact']` as an array with `st['Contact']=[];` first, otherwise CF will assume it's a struct
- Also, you are setting the array with `i`, but outputting it with `[#i#]` without any quotes. Use `#` in outputs embraced with quotes like this: `st['Contact']['#i#']['ID']` or without embracing quotes like this: `st['Contact'][i]['ID']`. But not the like this `st['Contact'][#i#]...`.

Correcting your code to make `st.Contact` be populated as an array, it could be similar to:

**Alternative 1:** Use `ArrayAppend()` or `append()` member function:

```javascript
st['Contact']=[]; 
for ( i in myquery ) {
      st['Contact'].append( 
         {"id": myquery.id,
         "name": myquery.name,
         "email": myquery.email
         });
    }
```

same but simplier:

```
st['Contact']=[]; 
for ( i in myquery ) {
      st['Contact'].append( i );
    }
```

**Alternative 2:** Iterate the query by index with `for (i = 1; i <= myquery.recordCount; i++)`

```javascript
st['Contact']=[]; 
for (i = 1; i <= myquery.recordCount; i++) {
    st['Contact'][i]['ID'] = myquery.id[i];
    st['Contact'][i]['Name'] = myquery.name[i];
    st['Contact'][i]['Email'] = myquery.email[i];
            }
```

If you dump the variable `st` with the help of the query I've submitted, you'll get the following data structure (here it's simply stringified):

```
{"Contact":[
    {"Name":"Antonio","ID":43,"Email":"antonio@somedomain.com"},
    {"Name":"Manuel","ID":65,"Email":"manuel@somedomain.com"},
    {"Name":"Paula","ID":77,"Email":"paula@somedomain.com"},
    {"Name":"Jennifer","ID":87,"Email":"Jennifer@somedomain.com"}
    ]}
```

Here is the complete cfscript code of both alternatives:

```javascript
myquery= queryNew(
            "id, name, email",
            "integer,varchar,varchar",
            [ 
                {"id":43,"name":"Antonio", "email": "antonio@somedomain.com"}, 
                {"id":65,"name":"Manuel", "email": "manuel@somedomain.com"}, 
                {"id":77,"name":"Paula", "email": "paula@somedomain.com"},
                {"id":87,"name":"Jennifer", "email": "Jennifer@somedomain.com"}
                
            ]);
            
st['Contact']=[]; 
for ( i in myquery ) {
      st['Contact'].append( 
         {"id": myquery.id,
         "name": myquery.name,
         "email": myquery.email
         });
    }
dump(st);

// simplier version of above
st['Contact']=[]; 
for ( i in myquery ) {
      st['Contact'].append( i );
    }
dump(st);


st['Contact']=[]; 
for (i = 1; i <= myquery.recordCount; i++) {
    st['Contact'][i]['ID'] = myquery.id[i];
    st['Contact'][i]['Name'] = myquery.name[i];
    st['Contact'][i]['Email'] = myquery.email[i];
}
dump(st);
```

Comment: `var aData = [];
                for(i in myquery) {
                    tmpStruct = {};
tmpStruct['ID'] = i.id;
arrayAppend(aData, tmpStruct);
                }

                st['QueryData'] = aData;`